# how to redirect page in server uses header

Tags: php

```
<?php
     }
      else
      {
         $uname=$_POST['uname'];
            $password=$_POST['pass'];
          require('connect.php');
        global $pdo;
             $stmt=$pdo->prepare("select name,pass from admin where name=?");
             $stmt->bindparam(1,$uname);
              $stmt->execute();
               $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);           
              if($row['name']==$uname and $row['pass']==$password)
        {
        $_SESSION['user']=$uname;
        $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                     $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/');
                       $extra = 'principal.php';
                    header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");

        }
        else
        { 
        echo"your password and username incorrect";
         header('Location:http://localhost/adminp.php');
        }
          unset ($pdo);
          }
             ob_end_flush();
                  ?>
```

header for redirect page not working
in my local host code(header('Location:mypage.php') working fine but in server is not working

Comment: here have you got error like "header already sent"?

Comment: not use any echo statment before header check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196766/php-a-limit-to-the-amount-of-output-allowed-before-a-header-location-redirect-is

Comment: no error sir  please tell me what syntax used in server

Comment: can you please echo "$host$uri/$extra" ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ob_start(); at top of the code and ob_flush(); at the bottom of your code.
then use header code as follow -

```
header('Location:adminp.php');
```

Comment: use this header("location: admin.php"); exit();

Comment: : Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/schoolsm/public_html/header.php:9

Answer (score 0):

remove the `echo` statement above the `header` tag,
and please mention the error in your question .. if you get the error like `header already sent` then you remove the echo statement otherwise you try java script method like

```
 else
        { 
        echo"your password and username incorrect";
        ?>
        <script>
          window.location='admin.php';
       </script>
   <?php
        }
```